# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof CustomerInput'

Tags: typescript

I know this question was asked multiple times but at this point, I feel like this error could show up in multiple cases and I can't find the answer to this problem.

Here is the type that I have:

```
export type CustomerInput = {
  email: string;
  firstName?: string;
  lastName?: string;
  phone?: string;
  id?: string;
  locale?: string;
  tags?: string;
  metafields?: Array<MetafieldInput>;
  acceptsMarketing?: boolean;
  acceptsMarketingUpdatedAt?: string;
  marketingOptInLevel?: CustomerMarketingOptInLevel;
  addresses?: Array<AddressInput>;
  note?: string;
  privateMetafields?: Array<PrivateMetafieldInput>;
  smsMarketingConsent?: CustomerSmsMarketingConsentInput;
  taxExempt?: boolean;
  taxExemptions?: Array<string>;
};
```

I am trying to map other type to return object: CustomerInput like so:

```
  const customerInput: CustomerInput = {
    email: ''
  };

  Object.keys(row).forEach((property: string) => {

    let propValue = row[property as keyof ExcelRow] as boolean | string;
  
    if (propValue === 'false') {
      propValue = false;
    } else if (propValue === 'true') {
      propValue = true;
    }

    // ...

    if (property && property.startsWith('CustomerInput.')) {
      // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof CustomerInput'
      const customerProperty: keyof CustomerInput = property.replace('CustomerInput.', '');
      if (customerProperty.length > 0 && customerProperty) {
        // Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
        // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)
        customerInput[customerProperty] = propValue;
      } 
    }
  });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replace` returns `string` type, you cannot assert a string to be `keyof CustomerInput`. If you know that string replacement will return `CustomerInput` key certainly, you can cast it by `as` like below:

```
const customerProperty: keyof CustomerInput = property.replace('CustomerInput.', '') as keyof CustomerInput
```

For the second case, you can reassign the object instead of direct value assignment

```
customerInput = {
    ...customerInput,
    [customerProperty]: propValue
  }
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcDCBXAzjCBbYKASQDswN4BeOAbwCg45g8BDASwBsB+ALjhyhsSAcwDcDOADM2UHADkWBXvxiCR4xhxbzFwZQKFiJYABYQSevgfUS2AE32rDGuBwgBjFh0sq1RxjAswliOfi6BIACiIMxgMMoARhAQ3iwk4SxRMXhxbOYhfACCUFAsiAA81sIAfOIAvuJ07vnwYFAQKLCIVk4icNQARJg4+ISk5DAAdMzsHAN0TS1w7ti4BFAACu2dSHwA1sCIEJLoq6PEZBT9cG0dhEiTUMBgWu7AABQA5MNrY5dTnwANHBPp8AJRwbRwA5HE4-c7jCgLbzwFYjdaImB8eEY-7XGh1BbNEg4G7bABqXgwwD4SRSwDScAAPr5DNcBhYAO4DRpsSTvNG-Tbbe6IOAAMnFyzO6y2dy6k28IhgJgh9EYgoReOo6sYcEmBs1uImgIkjAA2kbCHKdogALp8W5gSkcakSQmEoA)

Comment: Thanks! That worked. But still the second error is still up:
`// Type 'string | boolean' is not assignable to type 'never'.
 // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.ts(2322)`

Comment: I just updated my answer for your 2nd case, @TwistedOwl

Comment: Amazing! Thank you. Can you explain why it didn't work as is? It puzzles me a lot

Comment: You have a bunch of keys with different types in `CustomerInput`, and it does not know which key you're trying to populate `propValue` because `customerProperty` is dynamic. If you add a condition like `typeof propValue === 'boolean' && customerProperty === 'taxExempt'`, we know `taxExempt` has the same type as `propValue` (for example), the error won't show up. For the above fix, we're trying to create a new object, and populate a dynamic key which we don't know yet in the compile time, so that's why it's passed. @TwistedOwl

Comment: I think that makes sense. It feels a bit like tricking TS so it works the way we want it to work. For some reason I can't stop looking at it as it's the same thing but written a bit differently